# LLM batch input/batch output in a single call using Langchain

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai, gpt-4

I have a long list of items (let's say sport teams). There are over 1 million items in my list. And I need LLM to provide me with the information on some fields, such as coach name, city, website, and a few more.

I realised If in each call I feed in let's say 25 of those items it would be a lot much cheaper than feeding them one by one. I want the output be in Json format. However, sometimes LLM spit out broken Json. That's why I am using langchain to add Json schema and format instructions. However,  langchain output parser fails because it expects the Json output includes the information for one item only while I have multiple. Can Langchain handle a case like mine or I have to manually implement the output parsing and fallbacks?

Here is a code to replicate the problem, my real problem have a much longer prompt. That's why I want to save money by batch inputing in each call.
In the code below, ensure adding your own keys.

Thank you in advance for your help.

````
#%%
import logging
import os
import openai
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
import sys
 
#%%
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from langchain.prompts.chat import HumanMessagePromptTemplate, SystemMessagePromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate, BaseStringMessagePromptTemplate
from langchain.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser, OutputFixingParser, RetryOutputParser, RetryWithErrorOutputParser
from langchain.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field, validator
 
#%%
team_names_input =  ["FC Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Bayern Munich", "Manchester City", "Paris Saint-Germain", "Bayern Munich", "Liverpool", "Juventus", "Manchester City", "Leipzig", "SSC Napoli", "FC Porto"]
 
# metadata fields
metadata_fields = ['Sport_team', 'stadium', 'coach',
       'city', 'country', 'website']
 
#%%
model = AzureChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_key = openai.api_key,
    openai_api_base = openai.api_base,
    deployment_name = openai.deployment_name,
    openai_api_version = openai.api_version,
    openai_api_type = openai.api_type,
    temperature = 0.1
)
 
#%%
 
class metdata(BaseModel):
    Sport_team: str = Field(description="Sport_team")
    stadium: str = Field(description="stadium")
    coach: str = Field(description="coach")
    city: str = Field(description="city")
    country: str = Field(description="country")
    website: str = Field(description="website")
   
   
def construct_prompt_template(system_prompt: str, human_prompt: str) -> ChatPromptTemplate:
    system_message_prompt_template = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(system_prompt)
    huamn_message_prompt_template = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_prompt)
    template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            system_message_prompt_template,
            huamn_message_prompt_template,
        ]
    )
 
    return template
 
def get_completion_with_parser(prompt, parser, callback_info=False):
    with get_openai_callback() as cb:
        output = model(prompt)
    output_content = output.content
    response = parser.parse(output_content)
    #response = output_content
 
    if callback_info:
        return response, cb.total_tokens, cb.total_cost
 
    return response
   
# %%
 
def gpt_teams_metadata(metadata_fields, team_names):
    system_prompt = """
You will be given a list of sport teams and you are expected to provide the requested information for each team.
 
[The output should be in json format with the followings keys]:
<< 
```{metadata_fields}```
>>.
Think thoroughly about each single team individually.
 
Before giving the answer ensure all the requested fields are covered for each single team.
Output only the Json object nothing else.
 
```{format_instructions}```
 
"""
 
    # human prompt
    human_prompt = """list of sport teams are:
    ```{team_names}```, Output only the json object nothing else. """
   
    template = construct_prompt_template(system_prompt,human_prompt)
    parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object = metdata)
    format_instructions = parser.get_format_instructions()
   
    final_prompt_value = template.format_prompt(team_names = team_names,
                                                metadata_fields = metadata_fields,
                                                format_instructions = format_instructions)
   
    final_msg = final_prompt_value.to_messages()
    response, total_tokens, total_cost = get_completion_with_parser(final_msg, parser, callback_info = True)
   
    return response, total_tokens, total_cost
 

#%%
n = 2
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
output_json = []
cost = []
n_tokens = []
 
for i in range(0,2):
    print(i)
    team_names = list(team_names_input[i*n:(i+1)*n])
    response, total_tokens, total_cost = gpt_teams_metadata(team_names = team_names,
                                                            metadata_fields = metadata_fields)
   
    response_df = pd.read_json(response)
    output_json.append(response)
    cost.append(total_cost)
    n_tokens.append(total_tokens)
   
    print(f"total cost up to iteration {i} is {sum(cost)}")
   
    temp_df = pd.concat(
    [response_df, output_df], axis=0, join="outer", ignore_index=False,
    keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False, copy=True,
)
    if len(output_df) > 0:
        if all(output_df.columns == metadata_fields):
            output_df = temp_df
            output_df.to_csv("./LLM_sportteams.csv", index=False)
            print("format looks alright")
        else:
            temp_df.to_csv(f"./LLM_sportteams{i}.csv" , index=False)
            print("format does not look alright")
    else:
        output_df = temp_df
        output_df.to_csv("./LLM_sportteams.csv", index=False)
       
       
    time.sleep(40)
````

my real problem have a much longer prompt. That's why I want to save money by batch inputing in each call.
In the code below, ensure adding your own keys.

Thank you in advance for your help.